# Fontspec: Old-style numbers and fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, oldstylenums

I am trying to use old-style numbers in my LuaLaTeX document. My main font is "Cambria", which I do not want to change.

[image: old-style figures]

As you can see in this picture (line 2) there is a change in font. I do not want that change to happen if using the `\oldstylenums` command. The strange thing is that the normal text uses the right numbers. How can I easily change the style of that command too?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Cambria}%
\setsansfont{Calibri}%
\setmonofont{Consolas}%
\setmathfont[range={it,sfit}]{Cambria Italic}%
\setmathfont[range={bfit,bfsfit}]{Cambria Bold Italic}%
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}%

\begin{document}
    \section{This should have an old-style figure}
    This is a text containing some figures: 123456. They should be old-style and not lining. This is specifically old-style: \oldstylenums{123456}. And this is lining: \liningnums{123456}. And in math it shall be lining: \( 123456\)
\end{document}
```

*Update:* As you can see in the next picture there is a ordinary LaTeX font used in that document which is not supposed to be there.

[image: fonts in document]

Comment: the sfrm is coming from \usepackage{MnSymbol} if I remove that I just get opentype fonts (what do you want mnsymbol to do in this context)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for helping localizing the problem. I use `MnSymbol` in my main document to have nicer symbols (e.g. arrows). Do you know an elegant solution to not use MnSymbol for that macro?

Comment: well certainly loading a package that sets up math for 8bit font encodings after loading unicode-math is going to break something. hard for me to say, do you need unicode-math or can you just use the mnsymbol setup, or alternatively what's wrong with cambria math arrows...

Comment: Try loading `MnSymbol` _before_ fontspec.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks, it would have been so easy...
Please post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is textcomp that redefines \oldstylenums.

Comment: The incorrect oldstyle numerals show up with or without `MnSymbol` being loaded. They appear to be Latin/Computer Modern oldstyle numerals.

Comment: Glad it helped, but does loading `MnSymbol` first still give you the arrows you want?  I don't have the relevant fonts so can't test your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but not loading mnsymbol fixed that:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the comments, there is one main problem with the code: It uses `MnSymbol`. That loads, among others, `textcomp`, a package not intended for use with unicode fonts. The issue is resolved not loading the `MnSymbol` package.

Probably that is no real disadvantage, because the `unicode-math` provided font support is sufficient, especially using a font like "Cambria Math".

[image: correct fonts]

Comment: Why should `textcomp` be deprecated? It isn't. To the contrary it's part of base LaTeX. It doesn't make sense to load `MnSymbol` along with `unicode-math` to begin with.

Comment: I was just going to say this, when I found @egreg said it first. No reason at all not to use `textcomp`. Plenty of reason not to use it with unicode fonts.

Comment: @egreg CTAN marks it as "obsolete".

Comment: @TeXnician That's an old version of the package, that obviously became obsolete when a new one was made part of the base distribution..

Comment: @TeXnician The location of `textcomp.sty` in my TeX Live is `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty`

Comment: @egreg Okay, I've corrected it.